# Background thread Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a question about threading in android

If call a method which is in my activity from a **run()** method of a new thread is that method executed in that new thread or in main thread. for example.

```
  ...
  public void run()
   {
    someMethod(); //some method declared in activity  
    }
  ...
```

Comment: it will be executed in the new thread only.

Comment: Obviously only if you  start the thread: if you call yourThread.run(); it will be executed in the Activity's thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each Thread has its own stack, and given that `Threads` don't share stack. So, once a thread is started, then any method invoked from it will be executed in that `Thread` only.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Every method you call is executed in the current thread.

Comment: you mean it doesn't matter where it was declared. it will be executed in thread in which it was called. right?

Comment: Exactly. A given object's methods can be called by several threads.

Answer (score 0):

When thread is create it has it's own stack. So whatever methods you call from that thread is execute in that thread's stack only.